# Empty page displayed with cfcontent in a popup (unless manual refresh)

Tags: coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion page calling a cfm page as a popup through window.open(..). The target page is a cfm that loads a PDF file. The called page code is the following:

```
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="/deploy/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/myPDF.pdf"/>
<cfflush>

<script language="javascript">
 window.location.reload();
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting only a blank page unless I manually refresh the page (going to the popup URL bar and hitting Enter) to have its contents displayed by the browser.

What is strange is that if I replace the caller page code from window.open() to document.url =  the PDF is displayed without the need of refreshing the page.

Do you have any suggestions here how to call the target page as a popup and having it load without the need of a manual refresh?

Thanks.

Comment: The environment I am working on is a Suse/JBoss/JDK 1.5 one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are mixing javascript and PDF content together.  It should really just be this:

```
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="/deploy/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/myPDF.pdf"/>
```

This will return the full contents of that PDF to the browser.

What were you trying to do with the javascript code?

*edit* It sounds like it could be something to do with caching.  To prevent that, try adding some cache control headers to your file:

```
<cfheader name="expires" value="#getHttpTimeString(now())#"> 
<cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache"> 
<cfheader name="cache-control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"> 
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="/deploy/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/myPDF.pdf"/>
```

If that doesn't work, try adding this one too:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myPDF.pdf">
```

Comment: Hi Jake, actually before the code was just as you suggested but still the PDF did not come up unless I did a manual refresh from the browser. With the JS code I tried to force the browser to auto-refresh the page as I was doing when hitting enter (return) on the URL field. That is why I also added cfflush. Your code as my code works only when the caller does a document.url instead of through window.open. The latter requires a forced manual refresh in my case and I do not yet know why!

Comment: Jake thank you very much for your input. But, none of the code worked in my case. I have my system deployed on JBoss/Suse Linux maybe it could related to that too. But, I actually got it solved today. Just did a window.location to another cfm page containing the cfcontent tag (to load the pdf there)

Comment: Were you using the same URL to serve both HTML and PDF content?  If so, that is likely the root problem.  It's best to have distinct URLs for PDF (or any other mime-type) content, so as to not confuse the browsers.

Comment: What was strange was with your code (first code block containing the no-cache pragma), as was in my case, I was getting a blank popup (with the correct URL). The browser was like starting to download the PDF and then it stopped (without having a web or app level error). I had to go to the popup window and with the mouse go over the URL and hit Enter. Then, I got the browser to display the PDF! Weird!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I adopted was that of calling a proxy page and then that proxy page generates the PDF file. So:

1. `window.open('2')` // open in a popup the PDF
2. `document.location = '3'` // proxy
3. `cfcontent type='application/pdf' file='...'` // generate PDF

Why I cannot have 1 and 3 only is for now a mystery but in my case it works perfectly.